# Spring Data Neo4J Rest API Performance

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have been using Spring Data Neo4J over a REST and have noticed the performance issues which seems to be a known effect as stated in [Neo4J REST performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856471/neo4j-rest-performance).

I am currently using SDN 2.3.2 with Neo4J 1.9 and was just wondering if later versions of SDN 3.1+ with Neo4J 2.X have improved in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plans to improve it but currently little capacity on our side. Perhaps we get some work on it done in 3.2 or 3.3.

But you can move your SDN layer into the Server as an unmanaged extension. That works and you then can expose your domain level objects as REST endpoints to the front-end clients.

See: http://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/extending-the-neo4j-server-with-spring-data-neo4j/

Comment: So is utilizing an embedded database considered good production practice, it seems to me that a distributed implementation using REST is more appropriate.

Comment: @Michael Hunger 
Can you give a rough timeframe?